# How to REFERENCE one collection from another collection in MongoDB using json schema validation

Tags: json, mongodb

I have read many articles, posts, and stack overflow solutions for understanding how to reference one collection from another collection using JSON schema validation in MongoDB. I would appreciate it if you can give the solution to the problem with an example of how referencing works in JSON schema validation for MongoDB

Note: This is not an actual data model but something similar to the problem I am trying to solve
Q1) I have students' data and each student can have many courses.
**The student collection JSON schema is:**

```
db.createCollection("student",{
validator: { $jsonSchema: {
bsonType: "object",
required:["name", "dob", "course"],
properties: {
name :{ 
bsonType: "string",
maxLength:40,
},
age :{ 
bsonType: "int",
maxLength:3,
},
dob:{ 
bsonType: "string",
},
course:
{
 ### reference the courses collection to store data 
},
}
}
}
)
```

**and the courses collection JSON schema is this:**

```
db.createCollection("course",{
validator: { $jsonSchema: {
bsonType: "object",
properties: {
name :{ 
bsonType: "string",
maxLength:40,
},
instructor:{ 
bsonType: "string",
maxLength:40,
}, 
credits{

bsonType : "int",
maxLength: 2
}
}
}
}
)
```

I do not want to embed the course collection in the student collection but reference the course collection from the student collection. How can I do this in JSON schema for Mongo DB since $ref cannot be used to link two collections in JSON schema in MongoDB?

I would also appreciate links explaining the solution to this problem with a SCHEMA DESIGN example.

**Note:** I have gone through the whole MongoDB documentation, and JSON schema documentation to find a solution to this problem.